# Does this pronunciation of "consent form" sound strange?

Tags: pronunciation, dialect

Does this sound wrong or just a different way of saying
"consent form"? Almost like a dialect of some sort?

https://soundcloud.com/sunshine-sunflower-ken

Comment: The speaker sounds American, and there's nothing "wrong" with her pronunciation. There's too little for me to go on to know whether she is a native speaker, but it is possible that she might be Asian (Chinese, Japanese, Thai, etc.) Still, the recording is too brief to make any assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds wrong to me because it seems like the speaker is putting the stress on the first syllable of "consent."

The usual pronunciation of this word has the stress on the second syllable. And when the prefix "con" is unstressed, as it is in this word, the vowel is reduced as a rule, so it should have a schwa sound rather than a "short o" sound. If you know IPA: it sounds like the speaker is saying /ˈkɑn.sɛnt/, while the usual pronunciation of this word is /kənˈsɛnt/ or /kn̩ˈsɛnt/.

Some dialects do have different stress patterns in nouns (a well-known example is *police,* which is pronounced with stress on the last syllable by most speakers, but with stress on the first syllable by some speakers in the American South) but I don't know if this would apply to the specific word *consent.* In any case, even if the pronunciation exists dialectally, I would not recommend using it as an English language learner.